recaptcha returns a low result in most cases after account suspension
The account was suspend due to the absence of a payment account. After resolving the issue, this recaptcha problem appeared.
{
"name": "**redacted**",
"event": {
"token": "**redacted**",
"siteKey": "**redacted**",
"userAgent": "okhttp/4.9.2",
"userIpAddress": "5.77.24.232",
"expectedAction": "user_request_sms_verification",
"hashedAccountId": "",
"express": false,
"requestedUri": "",
"wafTokenAssessment": false,
"ja3": "",
"headers": [],
"firewallPolicyEvaluation": false,
"fraudPrevention": "FRAUD_PREVENTION_UNSPECIFIED"
},
"riskAnalysis": {
"score": 0.1,
"reasons": [],
"extendedVerdictReasons": [],
"challenge": "CHALLENGE_UNSPECIFIED"
},
"tokenProperties": {
"valid": true,
"invalidReason": "INVALID_REASON_UNSPECIFIED",
"hostname": "**redacted**",
"androidPackageName": "",
"iosBundleId": "",
"action": "user_request_sms_verification",
"createTime": "2024-12-23T10:52:21.988Z"
},
"accountDefenderAssessment": {
"labels": []
}
}

What could this be due to ?

There doesn't appear to be a programming problem here. If you think this 'problem' is due to your account suspension, rather than just coincidence, then you should talk to Google
